# Unable to get ObjectId after inserting using observable-mongo

Tags: node.js, mongodb, lodash

I am using observable-mongo package to interact with mongodb. After I insert a document using insertOneObs it returns ObjectId of the inserted document. But I am struggling to get to the actual ObjectId. What I get is below:

```
[ 'ObjectID', <Buffer 5d 18 5d 93 9b 7c dd 56 14 3a fa b7> ]
```

I took a peek inside the library and saw the below code returning the insertedId.

```
observer.next(_.values(result.insertedId));
```

Not sure why lodash function _.values is used before returning the ObjectId. But it has made it difficult to get at the actual value of the Id.
I have looked at lodash functions to undo what the values function does but failed to find any.

Comment: What you get is the right (actual) value of the document's [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/index.html) inserted on your DB. So, if you want the hexadecimal `String` representation of the ObjectId, you just can simply use the [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method over each Object you are getting from your result.

Comment: I tried to simply do a toString to the object and the result was:
ObjectID,]��/ӌ�C�w

Comment: Maybe issues with the encoding. Try `toString('utf8')`. Can check [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_tostring_encoding_start_end). Also you can get the `str` value from the result, but need to check the type declaration.

Comment: Tried different encodings and checked the documentation as well...No luck so far...

Comment: I opened an issue on github with the package observable-mongo. The author fixed the issue and put out a newer version. I am not able to post answers from my account due to poor ratings so posting this as a comment.